Magic Mouse occasionally stops responding
I have a MacBook M1 running the latest MacOS (but this happened with earlier versions). Every few days, my Magic Mouse will stop responding, the cursor just halts wherever it is while I'm using it. There's no message saying that it has disconnected.
If I turn it off and on, I'll get the disconnected message followed by connected, and it will work again.
It's not low on battery when this happens. It happened today with more than 40% battery.
After putting up with this for a couple of years, I assumed it was just a flaky mouse, so I got a new one. But the same thing happens with the new mouse.
I don't think it's a general Bluetooth problem with my MacBook. I'm using a Bluetooth Logitech keyboard and it never has a problem like this.
Has anyone seen a problem like this and know how to prevent it? It's not a major problem, since power-cycling the mouse always works, it's just a little inconvenient. Occasionally it happens when I'm doing something time-sensitive like playing a game.

Did you try to use the mouse on another surface than the one you are using it normally? I mean on another mouse mat? I actually had the same issue and it was because of the neoprene from the mouse mat I was using...

I'd test with a wired mouse for a while.**  It could be that the screen pointer is hanging due to some software problem, rather than an issue with the mouse itself.  ** (Or better yet, a Magic Trackpad.)

@benwiggy It's not inconvenient enough to buy another new mouse. And I hate trackpads.

OK, well in which case I'd see if you can isolate the problem some other way. Test Safe Boot mode; test a brand new user account. Maybe audit the installed background processes you have, e.g. Launch Agents.

@Dakta I've switched mousepads, it's a different color, I'll see if that works better.

@benwiggy It doesn't happen frequently enough that tests like that would be feasible. I can't use a new user account for several days to see if it doesn't happen.

For the same problem with two mice, that suggests the problem is not the mouse, and software is the next thing to try. Maybe use something like Etrecheck to produce a report of the state of your Mac, and post it here.

@benwiggy I ran EtreCheck, but the report is too big to post here.

Can you post it somewhere and link to it? DropBox, or Pastebin? (There's no personal data in it, btw.)

@Dakta I've been using the other mousepad for a few weeks. Today it just happened again, so it's not the mousepad.
